# Show the section only if custom taxonomy was chosen

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, template-tags

So I have a code where all items of my custom taxonomy ('colour') are displayed. I broke my head trying to show the section ("colour__chart") only if one of taxonomy items was chosen. In simple words, how can I show a section if at least one taxonomy item (tag for example) is chosen, and not to show this section if taxonomy item is not chosen?

```
<section class="colour__chart">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="color-chart">
               <h2>Colour Chart</h2>
               <hr class="divider">
                <?
            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'colour' );
if( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach( $terms as $term ){

        echo get_field( 'name', 'colour_' . $term->term_id ); 

        echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">';
        echo '<div class="color-chart__item" style="background-color:' . get_field( 'colour_acf', 'colour_' . $term->term_id ) . '"></div>';
        echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>' ;
        echo '</div>' ;
    }
}
            ?>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work unfortunately

```
<?php if ( is_tax('colour',) ) { ?>
    <section class="colour__chart">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="color-chart">
                   <h2>Colour Chart</h2>
                   <hr class="divider">
                    <?
                $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'colour' );
    if( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        foreach( $terms as $term ){

            echo get_field( 'name', 'colour_' . $term->term_id ); 

            echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">';
            echo '<div class="color-chart__item" style="background-color:' . get_field( 'colour_acf', 'colour_' . $term->term_id ) . '"></div>';
            echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>' ;
            echo '</div>' ;
        }
    }
                ?>
                </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    }
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: OK, let me make that clear. You want to show this chart only if given post has one of colors assigned? Right?

Comment: Hi @KrzysiekDróżdż yes you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already check, if given post has any terms assigned. All you need to do is to move that check earlier in the code.

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'colour' );
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>
<section class="colour__chart">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="color-chart">
            <h2>Colour Chart</h2>
            <hr class="divider">
            <?php
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    echo get_field( 'name', 'colour_' . $term->term_id ); 

                    echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">';
                    echo '<div class="color-chart__item" style="background-color:' . get_field( 'colour_acf', 'colour_' . $term->term_id ) . '"></div>';
                    echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>' ;
                    echo '</div>' ;
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```